# Improving Query Speed By "Normalizing"

Tags: sql-server, database-design, report

I am creating a dynamic report on some data. This is using a reporting database, and *I am only concerned about query speed*, not insert speed, or anything else.

My first plan was to start extracting datacubes on dimensions to improve speed, however, looking at the table, I have the hunch that there are some other improvements I can make first.

The table in question is already "denormalized", but in a flat fashion, it looks something like this:

```
|ClientName                  |ClientId|InterestingMetric|
---------------------------------------------------------
|'Very big long client name' | 55     | 51650           |
|'Very big long client name' | 55     | 51655           |
```

I have the hunch that before I start "denormalizing", I might be able to get some some speed improvements by "normalizing" the data first. My reasoning is, there are only a few hundred clients, so I could get a speed up by reducing the table size and by reducing the comparison time by "normalizing" columns like `client name`; single simple inner joins on ints are very fast in relational dbs anyway.

Queries are doing comparisons on `ClientName`.

I know every case is different, and I have to run metrics, but am I on to something by thinking I may be able to get a  query performance boost by "normalizing" basic columns like client name?

Comment: Does the table have only 3 columns? Please also give us examples of the queries you plan to run.

Comment: Never go on a hunch, especially with SQL Server. Test everything. The amount of data you're talking about matters, as do indexes, join types, number of data pages in memory, etc. So do your metrics and measure like with like. Flush the buffer pool and the drive cache before each run, measure CPU and logical reads, take into account worktables, all those good things. For "a few hundred clients", this will likely be the same speed as a join.